# Delete the original image after cropping it with the imagefield crop module

Tags: 7, media

The title says it all.
When I upload a big image of 5MB but I only need a small part of it I can cut out a part (=crop).
I can then use that cropped piece for other purposes.
But I never need the original image anymore because I have that one on my computer already.
Is there some secret option to enable so that the original image gets deleted after the cropping?

Do I have to change something in the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this link will help you more.
https://drupal.org/node/631142

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the linked content gives no solution for my issue.